# How to find node directory in drupal website?

Tags: drupal, path, ftp

im very new to drupal CMS technology. Previous developer had developed the our organization website. We recently shifted from one server to another server (godaddy) after everything is done one of research staff asked me to findout the node path to create a FTP details for them but I dont know how to find that path and route. please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

-Raju

Answer (score 0):

There is no "node" directory in Drupal. Drupal is working with "entities" and at start (i.e. before you install some modules that are creating new entity types) you have only one entity type - node. So every content you create is a node. Every node has unique id. You can access every node by that id like:

http://some.domain.com/node/node_id

Nodes can also be in different types ("Basic page", "Article"...) and every type can have different fields, but they all share the same set of id - you can't have 2 nodes with same id, even in different node (content) types.

But, of course, nodes can have more SEO paths. But there is no directory "node" with pages 1,2,3.... Drupal is using it's .htaccss to intercept that kind of paths and to display proper content, that is, if rewriting rules are enabled...